# Error: " No such file or directory " when file does exist

Tags: c, file

I have a command line program that expects the name of the file on process start or if not provided, asks for the name of the said file.

```
char* DataFile = NULL;

if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Enter the name of the file (relative or absolute): ");
    size_t bufsize = FILE_SIZE;
    DataFile = (char*)malloc(bufsize);

    if (DataFile == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed"); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fgets(DataFile, bufsize, stdin) == NULL) {
        perror("Error reading input");
        free(DataFile);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

} else {
    DataFile = argv[1];
};
FILE* fd = fopen(DataFile, "r");
if (fd == NULL) {
    perror("Cannot open the file");
    free(DataFile); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
    printf("Opened the file\n");
}
```

The way to start the program would be:

```
./main {NameOfTheFile.txt}
```

or

```
./main
Enter the name of the file (relative or absolute): {NameOfTheFile.txt}
```

The problem arises when I try to start the program without entering the file as an argument, the program reads the input, allocates the space, and doesn't open the file resulting in error provided by `perror()` even if the file exists on the system in the same directory as the program that's being ran is. This is what the directory looks like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kali kali 20848 Sep 23 11:09 main
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali  2397 Sep 23 11:09 main.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kali kali    10 Sep 17 09:19 test2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kali kali    60 Sep 16 11:28 test.txt
```

I added unnecessary permissions for testing.

I tried debugging with gdb (as much as my knowledge about debugging with gdb could provide) but the program ended with the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Have you printed the contents of `DataFile` to make sure they match your expections?

Comment: For the code that you shared -- that we can see-- when you start the program by entering the file name as an argument, it Looks like you do Not allocate memory as desired.  I only see allocation happening when there is no command line argument.  Not sure if this is root cause, but surely worth a look?

Comment: Also, I see a problem with variable 'DataFile'.  In the 1st code block, it is a read buffer.  Later, it seems to be used to hold the filename.  Inconsistencies like this can surely wreak havoc at run time.

Answer (score 1):

The `fgets` function will read a full line of text, *including the newline character* at the end of the line if there's enough room.  So for example if you enter "file.txt", `DataFile` will contain `file.txt\n` which is most likely not the name of your file.

You need to check if `DataFile` ends in a newline after the line is read, and if so remove it.

Comment: ... and to remove that final '`\n`' one way is `DataFile[strcspn(DataFile, "\n")] = 0;`